# Erro ao retornar endereço do CLGeocorder

Tags: ios, xcode

Eu estava desenvolvendo um app utilizando o CLGeocoder, e de repente ele parou de funcionar sem que eu fizesse alguma alteração no código, e passou a retornar o seguinte erro.

> ERROR /SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-187.4/Runtime/PBRequester.m:825 server (https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/fwdgeo.arpc) returned error: 500 /SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-187.4/Runtime/PBRequester.m:825 server (https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/fwdgeo.arpc) returned error: 500 2014-05-22 21:52:34.278 myApp[1626:60b] User canceled search 2014-05-22 21:52:34.282 myApp[1626:60b] User searched for

Meu código

```
- (void)handleSearch:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"User searched for %@", srBar.text);
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *location = srBar.text;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
                 completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                     if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                         CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                         MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                         MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapaView.region;
                         region.center = placemark.region.center;
                         region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                         region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;

                         [self.mapaView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                         [self.mapaView addAnnotation:placemark];
                     }
                 }
     ];
}
```

<sub>*Perguntado [também no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23819466).*</sub>

Comment: lee, se por acaso aparecer a solução lá no SOen, por favor publique-a aqui; e vice-versa ;)

Comment: Não consigo saber se a apple está resolvendo ou não, de toda forma eu reportei o erro pelo BUG REPORTING (17028449)

Comment: o problema ja foi estabilizado, acabei de testar e esta ok.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque era um erro nos servidores da Apple, conforme relatado na pergunta no SOen.

Comment: Engraçado que no SOEN está protegida pela comunidade.

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1401/7210)

Comment: A mesma resposta que postei no SOen eu respondi no SOpt, não sei se é possível mas gostaria que a pergunta fosse retirada do SOpt foi um erro da minha parte, e acredito que esteja gerando comentários desnecessários, já que por sua vez está sendo moderada no SOen.

Comment: leedream relaxa estamos só a debater para tornar o SOPT melhor...

Comment: leedream, don't worry, aqui a gente discute conteúdo, não pessoas ;) E, na verdade, a dúvida que este post levanta é bem interessante, tanto que [abri um meta post no SOen também](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256332/a-server-goes-down-affecting-many-developers-is-the-question-on-topic) pra saber o que a comunidade de lá pensa.

Comment: O BoltClock matou dois pássaros lá no Meta, o servidor tá retornando um [erro 500](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP#500_Erro_interno_do_servidor_.28Internal_Server_Error.29).

Comment: Não entendi bem a resposta do BoltClock, @brasofilo. Ele quer dizer que a pergunta deve ser fechada e excluída?

Comment: @bfavaretto, bom, entendo que ele não acredita que seja útil como "post sinalizador" de que esse problema ocorreu... Fechada sim, pois o problema não pode ser repetido; excluída, não necessariamente.

Comment: Note que `placemarks && placemarks.count > 0` pode ser escrita apenas como `placemarks.count > 0`.

Comment: De acordo com a discussão no meta, acho que chegou a hora de fechar.